# Handlebars.js not replacing tags

Tags: javascript, mustache, handlebars.js

I'm using [Handlebars.js](http://www.handlebarsjs.com) (or trying to) and even with a simple example, it's not replacing the actual tags with the data.

Here's what I have:

```
    <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     <div>Test Template</div>
     <p>Name: {{name}}</p>
    </script>

    <div id="template-preview"></div>

 <script>
 var source   = $("#template").html();
 var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
 var data = { name : 'first name'};
 $("#template-preview").html(template(data));
</script>
```

I don't get any errors and it displays the template within template-preview, but the `{{name}}` is empty. Any ideas if I'm missing something here?

Thank you!

Comment: Pretty new to Handlebars myself but could it be that it's pulling some cached/precompiled template?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (tested with Chrome). Which version of handlebars you're using?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
     <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     <div>Test Template</div>
     <p>Name: {{name}}</p>
     </script>
     <div id="template-preview"></div>

     <script>
        var source   = $("#template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var data = { name : 'Michael'};
        $("#template-preview").html(template(data));
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hm, stand alone that works for me too.  I'm also using Head.js - maybe it's related to that

Comment: Can you show more code then to see how exactly you're using it?

Comment: Ah - I think it's because I'm using handlebars within handlebars - Using handlebars in node.js, then in a template there, I have the other code.

Comment: in hbs file,view engine will replace all the delimiter with space